# Facebook ads for mobile iOS and Android application conversion tracking

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel

I have a mobile app and I want to add facebook conversion tracking.
I already installed the facebook sdk for both iOS and Android.
I do not understand from the documentation, do I need to add pixel? is the pixel only for websites and not for mobile applications?

The Faceboook sdk appears green, but I cant create leads, I receive the error:
A conversion event is required: When you set the post conversion for the conversion goal, you must specify the pixel_id and custom_event_type as the primary conversion. (#2446759)

But the events exist..

The documentation is not clear enough and outdated.

Do I need a pixel_id? if so, why I did install the facebook sdk? From what I know, pixel its needed only for websites.